# Converting Date string to DateTime Format vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datetime-format

I have this example and it gives me exception "Conversion from string x to dateTime is invalid"

here is my method to validate Datetime.

Example Date string : "27/03/1985"

```
Public Function validateDateColumn(ByRef FieldName As String) As Boolean

    Try
        If IsDate(FieldName) Then
            Dim actualDate As DateTime = CDate(FieldName)
            Dim DtLicExp As DateTime = CDate(actualDate.ToString("d", Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture))
            FieldName = DtLicExp.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
            Return True
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        'FieldName &= "Format must be MM/dd/yyyy"
        Return False
    End Try

End Function
```

any idea to validate this date string formate to datetime.

I want to convert this date "27/03/1985" to datetime.

I'm using asp.net with vb.net.

Comment: Why don't you use DateTime.TryParse : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h21f14e.aspx

Comment: I wannt to convert Date like that "27/03/1985" starts with days to datetime.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Have a look at using [DateTime.TryParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=VS.90).aspx) or [DateTime.ParseExact Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss(v=VS.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

This implementation will parse dates of the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and update the date string to the `MM/dd/yyyy` as you require. `DateTime.TryParseExact` allows you to specify the format of the date that you need to parse.

```
Public Function validateDateColumn(ByRef FieldName As String) As Boolean

  validateDateColumn = False

  Dim dateValue As DateTime

  if DateTime.TryParseExact(FieldName, _
      "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, _
      DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then

      validateDateColumn = True
      FieldName = dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")
  End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try the `TryParse` method.

```
Dim myDateString as String = "7/7/2010"
Dim myDate as DateTime
Dim isDate As Boolean = DateTime.TryParse(myDateString, myDate)

If isDate Then
    ' Yay I'm a real date
End If
```