# Converting Date string starts with days to DateTime Format vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime-format

I Have this date "27/03/1985" and because it starts with days i can't convert it to datetime.

Comment: Duplicate of this question, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327895/converting-date-string-to-datetime-format-vb-net, which has already been answered.

Comment: Please don't ask duplicate questions, you're not increasing the odds of finding an answer. Wait for your first question to turn up an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx

`DateTime.ParseExact()` lets you specify the format of the string representation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You just need to use the right culture specifier. It's a UK date so you need so supply the correct format provider:

```
dateValue = DateTime.Parse(dateString, culture);
```

where `culture` is of type [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.aspx)

[Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kc8s65zs.aspx)